# Steam age check circumvent by using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

So I want to make a scraper for steam games with Scrapy. I didn't know why exactly some games weren't showing in the result csv/json. I figured that it was because of the age verification form.

I really tried to see what was the problem... but everything seems like it should work. Can anyone help on this?

I noticed that the callback would return the same agecheck link and the dupefilter would remove that link. So the game would never be scraped.

Example games: Rise of the Tomb Raider, Doom.

This is the code:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    # Circumvent age selection form.
    if '/agecheck/app' in response.url:
        logger.debug(f"Form-type age check triggered for {response.url}.")

        form = response.css('#agegate_box form')

        action = form.xpath('@action').extract_first()
        name = form.xpath('input/@name').extract_first()
        value = form.xpath('input/@value').extract_first()

        formdata = {
            name: value,
            'ageDay': '21',
            'ageMonth': '5',
            'ageYear': '1975'
        }

        yield FormRequest(
            url=action,
            method='POST',
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_product
        )
    else:
        yield load_product(response)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam stores the result of submitting this form in  `lastagecheckage` and `birthtime`, cookies, so you may need to enable cookies on your scrapy project or passing them as custom values during the creation of a `Request` or a `FormRequest` using the cookies attribute.

You can read more about how to sent cookies [on the scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)

Comment: It worked <3 Thanks. I passed the cookies with custom values (cookies were already enabled on the project). 

But I do have one more additional question. Do you know how steam gets that birthtime value? I've used a known date with that value and it worked after that, but I am curious about how it is calculated.

Comment: I didn't check it but I think it is a unix timestamp